# Android Studio Unexpected Content Storage Modification

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

I am currently working on a project using Android development Studio. But everytime I try to create an application I keep on getting the error

> Java.lang.RuntimeException:java.io.IOException:java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected Content Storage modification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that was occurring was due to the fact that my wireless connection on my laptop was not good . Once I connected my laptop directly with my router, the issue went away.

Answer (score 11):

Try going to "File" > "Invalidate Caches/Restart..."

and then click "Invalidate and Restart" option on the pop-up dialog box.

This method fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`attrib -r .AndroidStudio\*.* /s`

Answer (score 0):

I had the really big issue as I was not able to open a project in Android Studio. Every time I start Android Studio dialog box appears that says:

```
Cannot load project: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: 
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected content storage modification
```

I solved it by doing following steps:

1.Close Android Studio

2.Go to the directory home_dir/.AndroidStudio/system/cache

3.Remove all the files in the cache directory.

4.Then restart IntelliJ